# React native background image and shapes

Tags: react-native, svg, background-image

I can't figure out how to make a background for a mobile application that has different shapes. If you can help me with some explanations / software or web applications I would be grateful.

I'm interested in how those blue curves can be made.

Many Thanks

[Background image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yESx1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be to create it as an Image (with paint editor such as 'paint.net' or other) and set it as [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground).

Another more complex way will be using the ["react-native-svg"](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) library.